# ExcelQueryFactory to read a password protected excel

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-excel

How can I read password protected Excel workbook using `ExcelQueryFactory`?

I am able to read the excel when it is not password protected using the code below.

`var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();`

`excel.FileName = "path of excel file";`

But when the excel is password protected the above code fails.

Answer (score 1):

This [useful site for connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) claims it is impossible, but offers [a workaround](http://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/) where the user is prompted for the password (via a GUI interaction) by the standard Excel COM object first.  Maybe you can adapt this?

Alternatively, to do it programmatically, see [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) for the parameters to Workbooks.Open() and try the same technique:  Open it via COM (and keep it open) then open it via LINQ-to-Excel.

(This is just a guess.)